# How to call a function in the use of getattr in python

Tags: python, web-crawler

Case 1 returns None, but I want to know why you don't see () as a function call and how I can use it like case 1 (if any)

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "lxml")

article_h = soup.select('ul.site-list a')
article_num = soup.select('ul.site-list div')
for i in zip(article_h, article_num):
    
    print(i[0].find('span',{'class':'txt'}).string)
    print(i[0]['href'])
    print(i[1].string)

#case1 
test = getattr(i[0],"find('span',{'class':'txt'})")
print(test)
>>> None

#case2
test2 = getattr(i[0],'find')
print(test2('span',{'class' : 'txt'}))
>>> <span class ="txt">...</>
```

Comment: I realize your question isn't asking about how to get a particular result, but I'm wondering a bit why you're considering using `getattr` here at all? The Pythonic way to lookup the `find` method of an object is `obj.find`. You only need `getattr(obj, methodname)` if the method name is unknown to you at programming time.

Answer (score 0):

Getattr tries to resolve the whole string, which is not found in case 1. Thus None being returned.
In sechs case, find is found and assigned. Thus you can use it later.

You could do

```
getattr(i[0],'find')('span',{...})
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work, because `getattr` does not write code and append the string and execute it.
Think of `getattr` as looking for a key (`"find('span'...)"` in your case) in a dictionary.
Such an item will not exist.